# While loop in Crystal Reports

Tags: database, loops, while-loop, crystal-reports, report

I have a database named `vw_AssetsWithEx` that contains measuring tools and info about these tools. With the following code I'm trying to find the minimum `Date of Maintenance` of these measuring tools (Column name : `tNextMaintDate`). However, we only take into account the tools who's Status is either `In Service` or `Limited` (Column name `cDisposition`). Unfortunately my code always returns the Date of Maintenance of the last measuring tool in my database instead of the minimum date.

Here's my code so you can visualize :

```
// Create a variable to store the minimum maintenance date
DateVar MinimumMaintenanceDate := Date(9999, 12, 31); // Initialize with a maximum possible date

Shared Numbervar MaximumIteration := 0;

While Not IsNull({vw_AssetsWithEx.cDisposition}) And MaximumIteration <= 9999 Do
(
    MaximumIteration := MaximumIteration + 1;

    // Get the disposition and maintenance date
    StringVar Disposition := {vw_AssetsWithEx.cDisposition};
    DateVar MaintenanceDate := CDate({vw_AssetsWithEx.tNextMaintDate});

    // Check if the disposition is "In Service" or "Limited"
    If Disposition = "In Service" Or Disposition = "Limited" Then
    (
        // Check if the maintenance date is smaller than MinimumMaintenanceDate
        If MaintenanceDate < MinimumMaintenanceDate Then
        (
            // Update MinimumMaintenanceDate with the current maintenance date
            MinimumMaintenanceDate := MaintenanceDate;
        )
    );

    // Move to the next record
);

// Display the minimum maintenance date
ToText(MinimumMaintenanceDate, "dd/MMM/yyyy")
```

Where is the problem in my code?